# How can I click to edit on a text field with ArrayController?

Tags: ember.js

I was following the tutorial but the tutorial is for the object controller. In an Array controller how do I properly pass in the object for the text field so it triggers the update for that model object?

Right now I can double click, and then type in some value, and if I hit enter I get the value plus undefined method set.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object asdasdasdasdasd has no method 'set'`

I guess it's passing the raw value into the controller and then trying to run methods off of that. How do I get it to pass the actual model?

View:

```
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li {{bind-attr class="isEditing:editing"}} {{action "editWorkout" this on="doubleClick"}}>
      {{#if isEditing}}
        {{view Ember.TextField class='edit' action="updateWorkout"}}
      {{else}}
        {{#link-to 'workout' this}} {{title}} {{/link-to}}
      {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  <li>
    {{newWorkoutName}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
EmberWorkouts.WorkoutsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  actions:
    editWorkout: (workout) ->
      workout.set('isEditing', true)

    createWorkout: ->
      title = @get('newWorkoutName')

      workout = @store.createRecord('workout', title: title)
      @set('newWorkoutName', '')
      workout.save()

    updateWorkout: (workout) ->
      workout.set('isEditing', false)
      workout.save()

  isEditing: false
```

Repo here if you want to investigate: https://github.com/ecl1pse/ember-workouts/tree/master/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an `itemController` in your `each` and then use an `ObjectController` for each item in your list.

```
{{#each itemController="workout"}}
  <li {{action editWorkout on="doubleClick"}}>
     <!-- Other stuff goes here -->
  </li>
{{/each}}

EmberWorkouts.WorkoutsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    editWorkout : function(){
       this.set('isEditing', true);
    }
});
```

Here's a JSBin of the general idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1038/edit

Comment: For those viewing this now, ObjectControllers have been deprecated since v1.11 (http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/).